# Meta theme-color e background com cores iguais

Tags: javascript, html-meta-tag, settimeout

Fala gente...(não liguem se eu falar qualquer besteira durante o texto, sou leigo em relação a isso).
Estou desde ontem desenvolvendo uma page usando configurações javascript para fazer uma interação.
Meus desafios eram:

1º Fazer uma página que alterasse de cor a cada atualização.

2º Fazer com que o meta theme-color e o background recebesse as mesmas cores a cada atualização da página.

Consegui realizar os dois primeiros desafios com a seguinte configuração, dentro do head: segue código

```js
<script>
//mudar theme-color
function getRandomRGBValue() {
    return Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255 + 1), 255);
}
function getRandomColor() {
    var r = getRandomRGBValue(),
        g = getRandomRGBValue(),
        b = getRandomRGBValue();
    return "#" + (((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1));
}

//recebe a cor que foi gerado no getRandomColor para utilizar a mesma cor, tanto no <meta theme-color> quando na função que muda a cor do body.
var CorBackTheme=getRandomColor();

//função executada para mudar o content do theme-color
function changeThemeColor() {
    var metaThemeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");
    metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", CorBackTheme);
 setTimeout(function() {
        changeThemeColor();
    }, 2000);
}

changeThemeColor();

//body collor
function carrega() {
 document.body.style.background=CorBackTheme;
 setTimeout(function(){
/*  carrega();
 }, 2000);*/
}
function atualiza(){
 setTimeout(function(){
/*  getRandomColor();
 }, 2000);*/
}
</script>
```

Se vocês entrarem no meu site ([cubomagi.co](http://cubomagi.co)) pelo sistema Android a partir da versão 5.0 no navegador Chrome, tanto o meta theme-color quanto o background ficarão da mesma cor a cada atualização de página que vocês fizerem.

Contudo, veio o meu terceiro desafio, ao qual não estou conseguindo realizar é:

3º Fazer com que as cores se alterem a cada 2 segundos.

O problema que acontece é: quando a função getRandomColor() gera uma cor, a variável global CorBackTheme recebe a cor dessa função, então eu uso essa variável na função changeThemeColor() e na função carrega(), que são as funções responsáveis por alterar a cor da meta theme-color e do backgroud a cada atualização da página.
Se vocês perceberem, dentro das duas funções (chageThemeColor e carrega), eu chamei o recurso setTimeout(), o qual é responsável por mudar a cor em um determinado tempo, mas deixei em forma de comentário pois não está funcionando. Todavia, ele até "realiza" a ação de alterar a cor a cada 2 segundos, só que ele altera para a mesma cor que a variável global CorBackTheme recebe somente uma vez.
No meu leigo conhecimento de lógica de programação, a ideia seria reiniciar o processo do getRandomColor() para poder a variável ColorBackTheme receber uma nova cor e então atualizar as cores da função changeThemecolor() e carregar() através do recurso setTimeout().

A pergunta é: como? (risos)

Na função: changeThemeColor(), se vocês tirarem a variável global ColorBackTheme e colocarem no lugar dele a função getRandomColor(), então o recurso do setTimeout() funciona, só que as cores do meta e do background não ficam sincronizadas, pois para cada função (changeThemeColor e carrega) a função getRandomColor() gera uma cor diferente.

Estou disponibilizando para vocês o documento através de um [link no google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B72dStII1nfudUVadkxaMXdGaEk?usp=sharing).

Obrigado por qualquer resposta e desculpem qualquer erro na descrição do problema.

att
Carlos Rebelo

Comment: Seria possível você criar um Fiddle?

Comment: Criei, mas não tá funcionando...

Comment: Não altera a cor do background...
Contudo, segue link: https://jsfiddle.net/migoseutonto/bqshtywu/